# Protected Cell warning when returning to original cell after DoubleClick

Tags: excel, vba

Not really critical because there are ways around it but curious as to why it happens?
Tested this on a brand new WB to be sure it wasn't something else buried in my code causing this.
I have a workbook with a protected sheet where I'm calling up a UserForm and using a Job# in one of the cells as a reference to work with. Upon exiting the UserForm, I want to leave the user with that same cell activated. Seems simple enough. Using the DblClick event anywhere other than the Job# column it works perfectly but if I DblCLicked on the cell that I wanted to return to, I get the protection warning.

To duplicate:

In a standard Module

```
Public ActRow As Long
```

Open Event

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Sheets("Sheet1").Protect userinterfaceonly:=True
End Sub
```

UserForm Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
    ' Doesn't matter whether the Unload is before or after
    Range("B" & ActRow).Activate
End Sub
```

Sheet1 Code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    ActRow = ActiveCell.Row
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

With the above code, if I double-click anywhere other than Col "B" on Sheet1, the UserForm will open up with nothing other than CommandButton1. If I press the Button I will be return to Sheet1 with the cell in Col "B" of the original row selected. No warning messages.
If I double-clicked a cell in Col "B" though, when I press the Button, I'm returned to Sheet1 and my original cell is activated but I get the 'Protected Sheet' warning message. Why?
Application.DisplayAlerts doesn't cure it nor does Unlocking the cell beforehand.
I'm left with activating the row below and then moving up a row to eliminate the warning message but that's just masking the problem.

Any Ideas?
Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your code without protecting the sheet, you will see double clicking on a cell in Column B will start an edit in that cell.  With the sheet protected, editing is not allowed, hence the error.

To avoid this, update your code to this

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Cancel = True
    ActRow = ActiveCell.Row
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```